# Como contar ocorrências de um numero em uma matriz?

Tags: python-3.x, lista, matriz

Preciso fazer uma função que conte quantas vezes um numero aparece em uma matriz, exemplo:

```
ocorrencias(9,[[9,7,6,9,8,8]])
```

Deve retornar 2

#### Meu código:

```
def ocorrencias(numero,matriz):
    cont = 0
    for elemento in matriz:
        if elemento == num:
            cont += 1
    return cont
```

Estou obtendo um erro dando erro quando existe mais de uma lista na matriz.

Comment: Marcos, você está quase lá. Não quero resolver o seu exercício por você e prejudicar seu aprendizado, mas a resposta para o seu problema está na sua própria pergunta. Quando você tem mais de uma lista na matriz, cada "elemento" da sua matriz é uma lista. Você precisa primeiro iterar cada uma das listas e então, para cada lista, você precisa iterar cada elemento. Ou seja, você precisa de dois laços aninhados para resolver o seu problema.

Comment: Consegui aqui! brigadao

Comment: Marcos, fique a vontade para postar sua própria resposta.

Comment: Posta a sua resposta que na sequencia vamos postar versões otimizadas.